# Choosing option from dropdown menu does not show what it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe someone can tell me how i can repair problem with choosing from Paypal/Bitcoin/Credit Card, coz i tried almost everything, nothing work like it should

I tried also to make them child()/children()/next() and so on nothing help

```
  <select id="payment" name="user-payment">
          <option value="select method">Select Payment Method</option>
          <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
          <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
          <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
        </select>
```

```
$paymentOptionsCard.change(()=>{

  // if credit card
  if($paymentOptions.val()==='Credit Card'){
    $creditCard.show();
    bullPay = true;
    }
  else{
    $creditCard.hide();
    bullPay = false;
      }
    });



$paymentOptionsPaypal.change(()=>{
   if($paymentOptionsPaypal.val()==="PayPal"){
    $paypal.show();
    bullPay = true;
  }
  else{
    $paypal.hide();
    bullPay = false;
  }});


$paymentOptionsBitcoin.change(()=>{
    //if bitcoin
    if($paymentOptionsBitcoin.val()==="Bitcoin"){
     $bitcoin.show();
     bullPay = true;
   }
   else{
     $bitcoin.hide();
     bullPay = false;
   }
 });
```

That's the variables /

```
//getting payment options
const $paymentOptions = $("#payment");
//selecting default as Credit card

const $paymentOptionsBitcoin = $paymentOptions.val("Bitcoin");
const $paymentOptionsPaypal = $paymentOptions.val("PayPal");
const $paymentOptionsCard = $paymentOptions.val("Credit Card");
```

I expect that code will "show" or 'hide' values and if that true or false attribute will assign it to the variables. 
Now it only show, without assigning all of them

Comment: why are you binding so many events? `const $paymentOptionsBitcoin = $paymentOptions.val("Bitcoin");` not sure why you are doing this.

Comment: Please show more HTML code to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind to the select with the change, not its options. You should just bind one change event to the select. This is a easy way of doing it without repeating a lot of code.

```js
// reference the select element
var sel = document.querySelector('#payment')
// add change event
sel.addEventListener('change', () => {
  // get the section that is active
  var paymentActive = document.querySelector('.payment-section.active')
  // if we have one hide it.
  if (paymentActive) paymentActive.classList.remove("active")
  // reference the option value that was selected
  var selection = sel.value
  // select the section based on the value
  var payment = document.querySelector("#" + selection)
  // show the section
  if (payment) payment.classList.add("active")
})
```

```css
.payment-section {
  display: none;
}
.payment-section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="payment" name="user-payment">
  <option value="select method">Select Payment Method</option>
  <option value="CreditCard">Credit Card</option>
  <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
  <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
</select>

<div id="CreditCard" class="payment-section">Credit Card</div>
<div id="PayPal" class="payment-section">Pay Pal</div>
<div id="Bitcoin" class="payment-section">Bitcoin</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear of the question but one mistake I can point out is that on the second and third onchange event the "if" condition seems to be wrong

```
if($paymentOptionsPaypal.val()==="PayPal")
if($paymentOptionsBitcoin.val()==="Bitcoin")
```

should have been

```
if($paymentOptions.val()==="PayPal")
if($paymentOptions.val()==="Bitcoin")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#payment').change(function(){
      $('.colors').hide();
    
      var pm= $(this).val();
      $('#' + pm).show();
    
      if(pm=='credit_Card'){
          console.log('Credit Card');
      }
      else  if(pm=='payPal'){
          console.log('PayPal');
      }
      else  if(pm=='bitcoin'){
          console.log('Bitcoin');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#credit_Card,#payPal,#bitcoin  {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button dropdown"> 
  <select id="payment">
    <option value="">Select Payment Method</option>
     <option value="credit_Card">Credit Card</option>
     <option value="payPal">PayPal</option>
     <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <div id="credit_Card" class="colors red"> Your Payment method is Credit Card</div>
  <div id="payPal" class="colors yellow"> Your Payment method is PayPal</div>
  <div id="bitcoin" class="colors blue"> Your Payment method is Bitcoin</div>
</div>
<footer>
<small>
```